# ASP.NET Authentication with login modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

The login modal is quite familiar for some web users on the internet. With a single click on the login button on the nav bar and the login modal pops up for you to sign in. I'm very impressed about this and try to take practie

Problem is I'm not sure to understand asp.net mvc authentication/authorization very well and don't really know how to do it.
let's say:

- I have 3 views: home, index, and secret. Each has a different controller and the secret page is restricted
- when I try to access to secret page at the home page the login modal popup, request me to login in order to access, same thing goes with the index page

How can i achieve this?
According to my understanding is that when an action has a [authorize] method, it will redirect you to the login page by the path you specify in the startup.cs file (normally is "/account/login"). But with the login modal... what path to put in?

Comment: Just make the endpoint `/account/login` show your modal.

Comment: hi @mxmissile Thanks for your comment, I haven't discovered the routing endpoint yet and this may be the answer i looking for. Do you have any document or example related?
I would appreciate it